# In nautilus how can I hide file types

Tags: gnome, nautilus, 14.10, file-type

Like on windows? There doesn't seem to be an option for this? Is this possible? it's annoying looking at the .xxx all the time.

Comment: @JacobVlijm Windows Explorer (the default file manager for Windows) used to hide the file extenstion (the 3 characters following the [.], in XP and Windows 7 by default. I don't know about 8 and later. Those who are from that world got used to seeing file names without the extension.

Answer (score 0):

In nautilus you can not hide a certain file extension.

**File extensions can be deceiving!**

But I wrote a **for loop** in shell for you:

```
for file in *.xxx; do mv $file .${file%%}; done
```

This will hide all files with .xxx extension in your current working directory.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to use a "." as the first symbol of the name.  Or you can put the file inside a folder and rename the folder by having a "." as the first symbol of the folder's name.
Examples:
.hidden
.folder
.hiddenfolder
.file
.title

Automatically, the folders/files will be hidden.  Then, when you want to see the hidden items again, you'll have to press **Ctrl + h** on your keyboard every time you want to see whatever's hidden.